# storage.set(object) only saving the last object

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm very new to javascript, so bear with me.

I'm parsing a JSON and want to store the objects into local storage. I have storage.set and console.log. The log logs all the objects, however when I check the local storage only the last object is stored.

JSON:

```
[
    {"id": 169, "year": "1997", "titles": [ "Sedm let v Tibetu", "Seven Years in Tibet", "Sedem rokov v Tibete" ]},
    {"id": 251, "year": "1949", "titles": [ "Šaty ze sedmi rákosů", "Sette canne, un vestito", "Seven Reeds, One Suit" ]},
    {"id": 404, "year": "1974", "titles": [ "Sedm zlatých upírů", "The Legend of the 7 Golden Vampires", "7 Golden Vampires", "Seven Golden Vampires: The Last Warning", "Qi jin shi", "七金屍", "The 7 Brothers Meet Dracula", "The Seven Brothers Meet Dracula" ]},
    {"id": 723, "year": "1957", "titles": [ "Sedmá pečeť", "Det sjunde inseglet", "Riddaren och döden", "Siedma pečať", "The Seventh Seal" ]},
    {"id": 1417, "year": "1967", "titles": [ "Sedm havranů" ]},
    {"id": 1418, "year": "1974", "titles": [ "Sedmého dne večer" ]},
    {"id": 1542, "year": "1966", "titles": [ "Sedmikrásky", "Sedmokrásky", "Daisies" ]},
    {"id": 2013, "year": "1940", "titles": [ "Pán sedmi moří", "The Sea Hawk" ]},
    {"id": 2292, "year": "1999", "titles": [ "Zelená míle", "The Green Mile", "Zelená míľa" ]}
]
```

Here's the code:

```
var JSONURL = chrome.runtime.getURL("final.json");
requestJSON(JSONURL);

function requestJSON(url) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
          var json = xhr.responseText;
          jsonParsed = JSON.parse(json);
            jsonParsed.forEach(function(object) {
                storage.set(object);
                console.log(object);
                // if (object.id === 2294) {
                    // console.log(object.year);
                // }
            });
      }
    };
    xhr.send();

    return true;
}
```

When I then check local storage using the background page using the code below, it returns only the last object from the JSON:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(function(result){console.log(result)})
Returns:
{id: 2292, titles: Array(3), year: "1999"}
id: 2292
titles: (3) ["Zelená míle", "The Green Mile", "Zelená míľa"]
year: "1999"
__proto__: Object
```

What am I doing wrong? It almost seems like each time an object is storage set, it rewrites the last one. How come?

Is the JSON format wrong?

---

EDIT:
I updated the JSON to look like this:

```
[
    {"169": {"year": "1997", "titles": [ "Sedm let v Tibetu", "Seven Years in Tibet", "Sedem rokov v Tibete" ]}},
    {"251": {"year": "1949", "titles": [ "Šaty ze sedmi rákosů", "Sette canne, un vestito", "Seven Reeds, One Suit" ]}}
]
```

Now it correctly saves it per ID. However I got another issue, I can storage.get by the ID but I cannot get for example the year property:

```
storage.get("169", function(result){
  console.log(result.year);
});
```

When I do only `console.log(result);` it works.

---

EDIT2:
Also tried having the JSON like this:

```
[
    {"test": [{"id": 169, "year": "1997", "titles": [ "Sedm let v Tibetu", "Seven Years in Tibet", "Sedem rokov v Tibete" ]}, {"id": 251, "year": "1949", "titles": [ "Šaty ze sedmi rákosů", "Sette canne, un vestito", "Seven Reeds, One Suit" ]}]}
]
```

When I `console.log(result);` it correctly returns as seen below, but I am still unable to access anything within. Probably because I don't know how...

```
{test: Array(2)}
test: Array(2)
0: {id: 169, titles: Array(3), year: "1997"}
1: {id: 251, titles: Array(3), year: "1949"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Tried foreach, tried looping through the array of objects, nothing worked.

---

Solved, thanks to Mr.wOxxOm!

Here's the code:

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;

var JSONURL = chrome.runtime.getURL("final.json");
requestJSON(JSONURL);

var titleID = "169"
//storage.get(titleID, d=> console.log(d['169'].year));
storage.get(titleID, function(result){
    var titles = result[titleID].titles;
    titles.forEach(function(item, i) {
        console.log(item);
    })
});

function requestJSON(url) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    //xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            var json = xhr.responseText;
            jsonParsed = JSON.parse(json);
            jsonParsed.forEach(function(object) {
                storage.set(object);
            });
        }
    };
    xhr.send();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The observed behavior matches the documentation: the keys of the object create values in the storage so you overwrite the same keys every time. You probably should simply save the entire array as one key.

Comment: I edited the first post

Comment: See the examples and tutorials: when using get() to get a `key` you need then to use result[key] e.g. `storage.get("169", d=> console.log(d['169']));` And in your last example the console shows us the array is inside `result.test` e.g. `result.test[0].id` and so on.

Comment: @wOxxOm that worked! Now I need to understand why. I updated the first post with the working code. I have one more question for you, if you don't mind - is it work checking whether local storage already contains the key I am looking for? I noticed that when saving new records it will not create duplicates. Now the question is whether it is overwriting the old records and checks for duplicates innately. If it overwrites the old records, i guess it would be worth checking for duplicates before saving. If the function checks for that by itself, than i would go just storage.set. Thanks a lot!